# Unauthorized Client on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, angular, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

We are using Google App Engine to host both server side code and a web app.
The server is used to handle Google Auth and access for Calendars.
It uses the server side authentication flow by generating an authorisation token from the client and sending it to the server to exchange for tokens.

This works well when running our client from our localhost but when we run through the same flow using the live client er receive an unauthorised_client error.

We've declared both the server side and client side domains under the credentials section, using both the custom domains and the originally generated Google App Engine paths.

Server side code using express. Obviously We've blanked out our client keys.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const {google} = require('googleapis');

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    "CLIENT_ID",
    "CLIENT_SECRET",
    "postmessage"
);

var code = req.body.code
var userId = req.body.userId
oauth2Client.getToken(code).then(resp => {
if (resp.tokens) {
  let tokens = resp.tokens
  res.json({status: "success"})
} else {
  res.json({status: "failed"})
}
}).catch(error => {
console.log(error)
res.json({status: "failed", error: error.message})
})
})

module.exports = router;
```

Client side code:
Angular 5+
ng-gapi to load Google api.

```
public getGoogleAuth(): Promise<any> {
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.googleAuth.getAuth().subscribe(auth => {
    resolve(auth)
  })
});
}

async googleSignIn() {
try {
  let auth = await this.getGoogleAuth()
  let { code } = await auth.grantOfflineAccess({
    'redirect_uri' : 'postmessage',
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
  })
} catch(error) {
  console.log(error)
  return Promise.reject(error);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you add app-engine URL as `Authorized JavaScript Origins` in Credentials (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)? Sounds like you only have `localhost` at the moment.

Comment: Can you share a stack trace of the error? `unauthorised_client` alone is not very helpful for the community to help you.